# Как обойти ошибку получив None вместо результата "NameError: name '*' is not defined?"

Tags: python, python-3.x

На Python 3.10 пытаюсь передать значения, если они есть, но получаю ошибку `is not defined` для не вызванных переменных:

```
def my_func_1():
   if a == True:
      b = 2
   else:
      c = 3

   my_func_2(param_a=a, param_b=b, param_c=c)


my_func_1()
```

на выходе ожидаю в функции my_func_2() похожие вариации вхождения:

- param_a=True, param_b=2, param_c=None
- param_a=False, param_b=None, param_c=3

Каким образом можно сделать заглушку, что бы если переменная не назначалась подставлять None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```py
def my_func_1():
   b = None
   c = None

   if a == True:
      b = 2
   else:
      c = 3

   my_func_2(param_a=a, param_b=b, param_c=c)


my_func_1()
```

Или вообще так:

```py
b = None
c = None

def my_func_1():
   global b
   global c
   if a == True:
      b = 2
   else:
      c = 3

   my_func_2(param_a=a, param_b=b, param_c=c)


my_func_1()
```

Переменные нужно объявить до их использования во внешней области видимости.

Comment: Да, спасибо!
Сам так же к этому пришёл!
Вернулся сюда что бы написать аналогичный ответ ))